# Google Maps API, error "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps

Tengo un listado de pedidos donde cada pedido tiene una dirección, yo lo que quiero es que me diga el mejor orden de entrega según la dirección de los pedidos. Para eso utilizo la API de Google Maps que devuelve en un array las posiciones.
Pero al ejecutarlo me tira el error:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8084' is therefore not allowed access.

listaPedidos.js

```
$(document).load(obtenerUbicacion());

var posActualLat = 0;
var posActualLng = 0;

var waypoints = [];
var cont = 0;

// OBTENER LA POSICIÓN DEL REPARTIDOR.
function obtenerUbicacion(){

    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(objPosition)
        {   
            posActualLat = objPosition.coords.latitude;
            posActualLng = objPosition.coords.longitude;

            ordenLista();
        }, function(objPositionError)
        {
            switch (objPositionError.code)
            {
                case objPositionError.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                    alert("No se ha permitido el acceso a la posición del usuario.");
                break;
                case objPositionError.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                    alert("No se ha podido acceder a la información de su posición.");
                break;
                case objPositionError.TIMEOUT:
                    alert("El servicio ha tardado demasiado tiempo en responder.");
                break;
                default:
                    alert("Error desconocido.");
            }
        }, {
                maximumAge: 75000,
                timeout: 15000
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Su navegador no soporta la geolocalización.");
    }
}

// Funcion transformadora
function translateWaypoints(waypoints, optimizar) {
    var params = [];
    if (optimizar === true) {
        params.push('optimize:true');
    }
    $.each(waypoints, function(idx, waypoint){
        params.push(waypoint.dir);
    });
    return params.join('|');
}

function ordenLista(){

    if (waypoints.length === 0){
        var div = document.getElementById("listado");
        div.innerHTML = "<h2 class='noHay'>No tienes pedidos asignados</h2>";
    }
    else{
        $.ajax({
            url:"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json",
            dataType:"json",
            data:{
                key:'MI_KEY',
                origin: posActualLat + ',' + posActualLng,
                destination: -34.911946 + ',' + -56.160502,
                waypoints:translateWaypoints(waypoints, true),
                callback:"?"
            },
            success: armarListado
        });
    }
}

function armarListado(info){
    var orden = info.routes[0].waypoint_order;

    var div = document.getElementById("listado");
    var i = 0;
    var temp = "";
    while(i < waypoints.length){    
        temp += "<div id='"+waypoints[orden[i]].id+"' class='listaPedidos'>";
        temp += "<a href='DetallesServlet?id="+waypoints[orden[i]].id+"'>";
        temp += "<p>#"+waypoints[orden[i]].id+"</p>";
        temp += "<p>"+waypoints[orden[i]].desc+"</p>";
        temp += "<p>"+waypoints[orden[i]].dir+"</p>";
        temp += "<p>"+waypoints[orden[i]].coment+"</p>";
        temp += "</a></div>";

        div.innerHTML = temp;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Revisa esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28360045/4092887).

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [ésta guía](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors) de Google.

Comment: @Mauricio ya puse "jsonp" y me tira error: Uncaught SyntaxError.

Comment: @guzgarcia estoy intentando hacerlo como dice ahí, pero no se como ver lo que me retorna, por ejemplo en el código que yo puse tengo success: armarListado y ahi llamo a la función que arma todo con lo que me retorna.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "no se como ver lo que me retorna"?

Comment: @JuanManuel, ¿cambiaste a `dataType:"jsonp",` y te sale ese error? Debe ser un error de redacción en tu código; en tu función _armarListado_ coloca `console.log(info);`.

Comment: @Mauricio ya puse el console.log(info) pero no me muestra nada, solo me muestra el error de syntax.

Comment: @guzgarcia claro yo en mi código tengo el info que es donde lo recorro para obtener los datos de json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se puede usar ajax con esta API de google maps porque te da el problema de CORS.
Lo resolví de este modo:

en el HTML puse: `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=LA_KEY"></script>`

en el javascript:

```
function ordenLista(){

if (waypoints.length === 0){
    var div = document.getElementById("listado");
    div.innerHTML = "<h2 class='noHay'>No tienes pedidos asignados</h2>";
}
else{
    translateWaypoints();
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsService.route({
        origin: posActualLat + ',' + posActualLng,
        destination: -34.377281 + ',' + -55.237778,
        waypoints: params,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: "DRIVING"
    },
    function (response, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
            armarListado(response);
        }
        else{
            alert("Error al mostrar los pedidos");
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Por eso te dije que sigas la guía. Las APIs de Google te requieren autenticación. Cuando te creas un proyecto en el panel de Google, te da una llave y, además, puedes agregar los hosts a los cuales se les permitirá consultar.